# Use an array formula to calculate datedif on criteria

Tags: arrays, excel, date, formula

Lets say I have a record of logged flights in a range, example below

```
    [A]      |   [B]   |   [C][D][...]    |    [G]
1  Date      |   Mode  |   More Data....  |    Days Since
2  1 May     |   Day   |   ....           |    Formula here
3  4 May     |   Night |   ....           |    Formula here
4  6 May     |   Day   |   ....           |    Formula here
5  8 May     |   Night |   ....           |    Formula here
```

I can use a formula to get the datedif between each row in column G, similar to

```
=DATEDIF(A2,A3,"d")
```

and copy it all the way down the column, but I'm guessing I need an array formula to go back and find the first row above the current row that matches in column B and get the datedif or days between those two dates.  I'm assuming an array formula, but what would the best way to go about that be?  I need the result to be the days between row 5 and 3 (night) and 4 and 2 (day) and then copied down about 300 rows...

I was looking at another array formula for sorting rows and eliminated blanks, but not sure how to adapt it to this scenario.

Comment: Is your pattern of Day-Night-Day-Night going to continue in the **Mode** column? If so, try `=IFERROR(DATEDIF(A1,A3,"d"),"N/A")` starting in `G3` and then drag it down as far as you need it to go (*you can also drag it up, but that cell will most definitely error out as it won't have a* `start_date` *cell to reference*). By wrapping it in `IFERROR` you won't need to worry about anything popping through as an error value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the difference in days you only have to subtract one date from the other.

`LOOKUP` function can be used to find the previous match, so try this formula in `G2` copied down

`=IFERROR(A2-LOOKUP(2,1/(B$1:B1=B2),A$1:A1),"")`

format result cell as number with no decimal places

Comment: Thanks, I had just figured it out using a helper formula in a hidden column using a MAX() array with an INDIRECT, but this is much cleaner, thanks!